# Can someone suggest a layout in Android for this?

Tags: android, layout

I'm developing an app from a specification and can't think how to layout this one screen in Android:

[image]

Comment: That is a very simple layout. What have you tried until now? What are those vertical bars?

Comment: Draw the sample layout in paint  then post as an image. If you post like this how can we understand?

Comment: Sorry, I meant to delete this question but forgot. At the time of writing I didn't have enough reputation to post an image.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's hard to say what your layout should looks like.

Looks like you need `LinearLayout` with horizontal orientation.

**EDIT**

Try something like that (I've skipped some parameters):

```
<LinearLayout
 layout_width="fill_parent"
 layout_height="fill_parent"
 orientation="vertical">
    <LinearLayout
      layout_width="fill_parent"
      layout_height="wrap_content"
      orientation="horizontal">

      <Button />
      <Button />

    </LinearLayout>

    <ListView></ListView>

</LinearLayout>
```

First of all - you should add an adapter to ListView, that draws views below the first line with buttons. You can do it by your own, there is a lot of examples. In this adapter you should draw views like that:

```
<LinearLayout
     layout_width="fill_parent"
     layout_height="wrap_content"
     orientation="horizontal"
     gravity="center">

     <ImageView layout_weight="1" />
     <LinearLayout
        layout_width="wrap_content"
        layout_height="wrap_content"
        layout_weight="1"
        orientation="vertical">

        <TextView />
        <TextView />
        <Button />

     </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: @Tiffany I've edited my post. Note, that it's not so hard to create such layout, so I've just giving you an advice - it's not completed solution.